# How to sed replace this end of the line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I want to replace this end of the line `[1-9] \\ \hline` by `[1-9] & \\ \hline` where a new ampersand. 
Data sample

```
The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  4 \\ \hline
```

My pseudocode where I am stuck to make a place holder for `[1-9]`, some holders for `$1` and `$2`

```
sed "s/[1-9] \\\\\\\\ \\\hline/*$/TODO/"
```

Expected output:

```
The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  &4 \\ \hline
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match one or more decimal digits followed by optional horizontal whitespace, then use `&` in th replacement test to re-substitute it after a literal ampersand `\&`

```
$ echo 'The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  4 \\ \hline' |
   sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\}[ \t]*\\\\/\&&/'
The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  &4 \\ \hline
```

or slightly more compactly, using extended regex

```
$ echo 'The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  4 \\ \hline' |
   sed -E 's/[0-9]+\s*\\\\/\&&/'        
The lorem ... & 1-2 & 3-4 & 5-6 & 6000 & 10000  &4 \\ \hline
```

Comment: Confirmed, both works. - - OK, testing more still.